# Moving average (running mean) - how to keep all observations in smoothed time-series?

Tags: r, time-series, mean, smoothing

Let's suppose I have a time-series of 100 daily values and I want to compute a 5-day moving average of this time series.

I would do as follows:

```
library(igraph)
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100)) # main time-series
df_mv_avg=data.frame(x=running_mean(df$x,5)) # time-series smoothed
```

It is almost obvious that `df_mv_avg` now contains 4 observations less (96) than `df`. However, in most examples of smoothed time-series, these time-series have the same length of the original (non-smoothed) time-series (in my case 100 obs).

How can I smooth a time-series (by n values) and at the same time keep the whole length of observations of the original time-series?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem occurs in image processing with mean filtering or other convolution operations, and it is solved in different ways by different "border treatments", which can be, e.g., *repeat*, *reflect*, *zero*, or *wrap around*.

As the *igraph* library function *running_mean* does not support a "border treatment" option, you must implement it your self and, e.g, repeat the edge values, reflect them, or whatever the wanted behaviour is, e.g.

```
x <- running_mean(c(rep(x[0],n-1), x, rep(x[length(x)],n-1)), n)
```